# sending email from localhost works but fails when run on remote linux server

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtp

Following is a simple python script to send emails using gmail smtp server. This code works from my localhost in my windows machine but when i run the same code from a remote linux server, "socket.error: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol" is thrown and the exception happens at this line " server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')". I appreciate any help on what is causing this error. Thanks!

```
fromaddr = ''
toaddrs  = ''

# Credentials (if needed)
username = ''
password = ''

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)

msg = MIMEText('This is a test message')
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg.as_string())

server.quit()
```

Comment: This may be related to IPv6.  Does your Linux server have IPv6 support?

Comment: hmm...its a godaddy server and i am not sure..so do you think smtp.gmail.com:587 maps to ipv6 address?

Comment: More the opposite, actually.  From what I last remember, GMail won't accept IPv6 connections if you don't have a reverse DNS record for your mail server.  A quick Google seems to indicate this is still the case (but I may be wrong).  So if your GoDaddy server is sending out smtp requests on IPv6 instead of IPv4, you may run into issues.

Comment: @blh83 thanks! do you know a way to switch to ipv4?

Comment: godaddy said "no I do not belive so as it would be sending from your shared hosting server and they do not use IPv6 IPs"